# I want to use a MySQL query result and use it as a variable string (MySQL, PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, email

Hey guys I keep getting the following error message when I try to run my PHP page.

```
Warning: mail() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /hsphere/local/home/mouseaccount/mouseaccount.com/problem_form_email.php on line 140
```

So from this I assume that what I'm using currently isn't storing anything as a string. Here is what I am using...

```
$sql = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE id='$log_id' AND username='$log_username'LIMIT 1";

$email_to = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
$email_subject = "MOUSE ACCOUNT - A Tenant has reported a problem";
```

And my mail function is...

```
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
```

I'm really new to web design, can anyone tell me how I can get the query to be saved into a variable I can then use in my `mail()` function? Many thanks!

Comment: `print_r` the variable you gave as 1st parameter and look what it contains.

Answer (score 2):

The statement

```
$email_to = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
```

is a query object not the data.

You need to fetch the result and then get the data as

```
$result = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 

$row = $result->fetch_assoc() ;
$email_to = $row["email"];
```

Comment: I added that In but now i get the following Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in /hsphere/local/home/mouseaccount/mouseaccount.com/problem_form_email.php on line 13 where line 13 is $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ;

Comment: That's right. "For successful SELECT queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object" Read http://php.net/mysqli_query

Comment: Meaning ur query is not getting executed use the following to see what error it is $result = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); if (!$result) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($db_conx));
}else{ do the fetch assoc to retrieve the info  }

Answer (score 0):

```
Pass all the variable  

$email_to="mail@mail.com";
 $email_subject="Subject" ;
$email_message="Message" ;
    mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
```

Comment: I do that later on it's the first $email_to I've got the problem with